# Check last element of hash map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I want to use a function for the update operation. So to create SQL query I must make sure the last element does not get coma(,)

I tried this

```
   public Boolean updateSingleClient(Map map, String id) {
        String updateSet = "";
        int count = 0;
        for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
            String value = (String) map.get(key);
            System.out.println("Count is " + count);
            count = count + 1;
            if (count == map.size()) {
                updateSet = updateSet + key + "='" + value + "'";
            } else {
                updateSet = updateSet + key + "='" + value + "',";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(updateSet);

        return false;
    }
```

Is there any way to check if this is the last element of HashMap?
Because this code is not working fine for me.

Comment: There isn't something like "first" or "last" element in the `HashMap` implementation.

Comment: So what is the best possible solution here?

Comment: So what is the expected input and output? Why do you use the raw `Map`?

Comment: can you please show us what you want to achieve what is map what it can hold, what is id what is the expected output?

Comment: If we use update query it usually has updateSet like we want to update name, number, date,
So, I want to create a function where I just past those value as map and id of row.
And it will run an update query.

Comment: You absolutely need to learn about prepared statements. Passing values directly as you're doing opens your code to SQL injection attacks (and will fail as soo as a value contains a single quote). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Not to mention, of course, that it will only work if all the values are strings.

Comment: What if I use the getter setter method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `StringBuilder`:

- Append elments to `StringBuilder`
- Remove last `,`

Sample code:

```
public Boolean updateSingleClient(Map map, String id) {
    StringBuilder updateSet = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
        String value = (String) map.get(key);
        updateSet.append(key + "='" + value + "',"); 
    }
    updateSet.deleteCharAt(updateSet.lastIndexOf(","));
    System.out.println(updateSet);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last element in the iteration will be at `map.size() - 1`, not at `map.size()`.

But note you can save a lot of this boilerplate code by streaming the map in to `Collectors.joining`:

```
String result = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .map(e -> e.getKey() + " = '" + e.getValue() + "'"
       .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```